# datatables: change date format

Tags: codeigniter, datatables, datatables-1.10

my JS:

```
$(function() {
$("#mytable").dataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
        "url": JS_BASE_URL + "work/dataTable",
        "type": "POST"
    },
    columns: [
        { data: "customer_name" },
        { data: "work_date" }, 
        { data: "work_time"},
        { data: "work_text"},
    ],
    columnDefs:     {   
        type: 'de_date', targets: 1 }
}).dataTableSearch(500); });
```

Data in `work_date` has the format: 2015-08-09 
I would like to change it to: 09.08.2015. 
`date-de.js` is loaded, columnsDefs is configured as written on datatables.net. 
 
 It doesn't change the format of the date, I still get 2015-08-09. Can it be a problem that I use Codeigniter 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `columnDefs` option, where `targets` is zero-based column number:

```js
this_table = $('#lancers_grid').dataTable({
// ...
columnDefs : [
    {
    targets : 1,
        render : function(this_date){
            //Here you should call the date format function:
            return datejs_format_function(this_date);
        }
    }]
// ...
});
```